# Twilio AMD in .NET API?

Tags: asp.net, twilio

I'm trying to use the twilio .net API with the new AMD. Ive tried updating my package to the latest alpha, but i still don't see an option for MachineDetection?

According to the documentation: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection

I should be able to set the parameter MachineDetection to either Enable or DetectmessageEnd

My Twilio REST API package is 5.5.3-alpha2, am i doing something wrong?

```
Dim Opt = New CallOptions
        Opt.From = Settings.MyTwilioNumber
        Opt.To = "+****"
        Opt.Url = "****"
        Opt.StatusCallback = "****"
        Opt.StatusCallbackEvents = New String() {"initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed"}
        Opt.MachineDetection = "Enable"
```

Compiler throws an error saying that property **MachineDetection** does not exist.

Comment: What property doesn't exist? Be specific.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

I think the type you're looking for is `CreateCallOptions` instead of `CallOptions`. Give that a try and let me know if that works out.